# where can i find detailed docs for IIS server event id's with their description?

Tags: iis, documentation

i have been googling for hours now and cant find a thing. There are plenty of articles/blogposts/forum_articles (from MSDN) on some specific events and their resolution etc ; but i simply cant find a single doc where they have listed all the event ids and given a short description of what they are for .. kindly help

Answer (score 1):

You can check [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/da3c59a8-c957-4cc7-b93c-0b3b81a4291b.mspx?mfr=true)(Server side Event List) and [there](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/af0a2e97-0c46-4e0a-9f2f-bdbe4a220c49.mspx?mfr=true)(Whole IIS Event List).

Answer (score 0):

This site provides a list of Events and Errors for each IIS Managed Entity:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd364124(v=ws.10).aspx

By clicking the links in the "Managed Entity" table, you can ultimately view the Event IDs for that managed entity.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way, I posted that question 4 years ago lol. It is so wonderful someone answered even 4 years later. I have since changed jobs a couple of times! No more Microsoft for me lol.